# Accessing data "cell" after reading csv file into R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

Newbie, so please be gentle. On Windows 10,trying to read a csv file into R (by row (across), if possible), create a 60X4 matrix and access the data by "cell". When I try to access row 2 column 3 (for example), I get ALL of column 3 returned. I only want the one piece of data. What am I doing wrong?

```
> A <- read.csv("xxx.csv",header=TRUE)
> B <- matrix(A,nrow=60,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
> B[2,3]
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  4  2  5  2  2  2  8  9  3 12  2  9  6 12  4  8  6 12  7  9 12  9  4  2  8  3  3  3  1  3  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  3  1  1  2  3  1  2  3  4  3  2  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1
```

Comment: Try `as.matrix()` instead of matrix.

Comment: @Al S Could you please show us a bit of A?

Comment: Use A[2,3], to directly access the element in the data.frame.  The is amount of data, it is generally easier to work with the dataframe as opposed to converting to a matrix.

Comment: Check what kind of data you actually loaded via `class(A)` .Quite possibly you've read everything in as characters, or some such.

Comment: akash87..  Here is a small piece of the data Person 1 Person 2 Person 3 Person 4
1 1 1 1
1 1 2 2
4 3 4 4
2 2 2 2
2 3 5 4
10 2 2 10

Comment: I apologize for commenting, but the as.matrix works, and I do not see a grey checkmark to toggle to stop others from working on a solution, as well as "saying thanks".  Not sure how to mark it!